# How would you craft a prompt to tell Stable Diffusion (through Automatic1111) to change the color or surface effect of an an object

Tags: prompt-design, stable-diffusion

How would you craft a prompt to tell stable diffusion, using the Automatic1111 interface, to change the color or surface effect of an object without substantively changing the other details?

For example, I have a reference image of a set of brown cardboard boxes that I used to generate a stack of Christmas gifts. Everything is great except Stable diffusion made the boxes a color that I don't want (Gold, likely based on the original brown coloration). I like the images that it is producing but want some color variations, and for some to be shiny and others to be matt.